# JPA performance improvement with reducing number of columns in query

Tags: sql, performance, hibernate, jpa

I have a big table that has many columns. In different use cases I need to load different columns from this table, but usually I don't need all of the columns. So now I think I should select the necessary columns from this big table.

For example I have a simple POJO like UseCase1 and I use this named query:

```
SELECT NEW UseCase1(t.a, t.b, t.c) FROM MyBigTable t
```

In update statements I also update only a, b, c fields.

So the question is, this is a good solution, to improve performance if I can't change the table? And will this improve the performance? :)

Comment: Can you add indexes to the table?

Comment: Yes I can, but if I add indexes the amount of sended data on network will remain the same.

Comment: You can only tell if it's worth it by measuring. But usually, you don't gain much by doing this. You'd better make sure that the query is fast by analyzing it and defining indexes, and make sure to use a query that returns only the needed rows (your example selects all the rows, which is usually a very bad idea)

Comment: @JB Nizet: It is just a simple example, I use pagination and maybe StatelessSession, because I use Hibernate as JPA implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had similar situations, and you can see the performance improvement using this technique in 2 cases.

1. If your table has more than 40-50 columns and you want only 5-10 values to be selected.
2. If your Bean defines a non-Lazy collection mapping. Then avoiding this property in the constructor will be huge saving.(This one worked for us tremendously)

Like @JB told, when we speak about performance nothing can be finalized without measuring it.These 2 point were my general experiences.

Comment: Hi ManuPK, the first case is mine, I have a table with ~40 columns and in most cases I just need 10-20 columns. I am in middle in implementataion (refactoring from old Entity Beans to JPA), and I want to do performance optimization after I finish refactoring, and yes I want to do mesurements. :) I just wanted to know if anyone had experiences with similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also lazy-load individual non-relation fields (e.g. Strings) by using @Basic(fetch = LAZY), e.g.

```
@Basic(fetch = LAZY)
private String description;
```

The table column for this field will not be loaded. Be careful that when you DO access the field that it will be lazy loaded with a single query which has the potential to become a different performance problem (N+1 select).